# Can we extract Workable API and display it via html or JavaScript code externally?

Tags: javascript, json, fetch-api

I'm trying to extract the Workable API and display all the jobs listings into an external site.

The API documentation is here: https://workable.readme.io/reference/generate-an-access-token.

It says on the notes here:

> Workable does not support Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)`

[image]

And when I try to fetch it says `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is present on the requested resource. How do I enable it? Because the Integrations settings under workable only allows me to only generate access token.

[image]

This is a sample code here when you go to this [jobs documentation](https://workable.readme.io/reference/jobs):

Note: I'm only using JavaScript

```
const options = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {accept: 'application/json', Authorization: 'Bearer AccessTokenHere'}
};

fetch('https://subdomain.workable.com/spi/v3/jobs?limit=50', options)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(response => console.log(response))
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: Please include actual error messages as text, not screenshots. Additionally, you can't enable CORS for somebody else's service, that is their decision to make, not yours. If they don't support CORS, make the requests from your server instead of a user's browser.

Comment: Legally, I don't think so, but technically you can host a server, and have the client-side requests go to your server, and your server fetches from the external API, and responds with it. Think of your server as a proxy.

Comment: @EricFortis Where does legality enter into this?

Comment: I'm using webflow to host the site. I think webflow doesn't have any server. I'm trying to ask in stackoverflow because there's no resources dealing with workable api.

Comment: You cannot use this api from JavaScript in a Browser. You have to access it from server side code or a desktop-application.

Comment: @NineBerry so you mean an application. Would like to limit it via Vue JS application. This possible right?

Comment: If the Vue.js application runs inside the browser, then no, this won't change anything. This will only work if you're outside a browser like for example a desktop application, a mobile application or server-side code.